Запуск Forge-версии с Minecraft-launcher-lib
Всем добрый день. Помогите пожалуйста: я не могу понять, как запустить forge с использованием библиотеки minecraft-launcher-lib. Перечитав документацию с ног до головы не смог понять, как это реализовать.
Сам вопрос: Как запустить minecraft FORGE?
Мой текущий код:
import minecraft_launcher_lib as mclib
import subprocess

def start(username,version):
    forge_ver=mclib.forge.find_forge_version(version)
    minecraft_directory = mclib.utils.get_minecraft_directory()
    mclib.install.install_minecraft_version(versionid=version, minecraft_directory=minecraft_directory)
    options = {
    'username': username,
'token':'offline',"launcherName": "LavLauncher"}
    mclib.forge.install_forge_version(forge_ver, minecraft_directory)
    subprocess.call(mclib.command.get_minecraft_command(version=version, minecraft_directory=minecraft_directory, options=options))
    return

P.s: Функция запускается из другого файла

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.
